# Why the code prints the extra line in the beginning and also after accepting 2 string it takes 0 to 2 which is 3 iteration to print the output?

Tags: java, for-loop

Why does this code print an extra line in the beginning, and also after accepting 2 strings it takes 0 to 2, which is 3 iterations to print the output?

[image]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {   String s1="",s2="";
            String str;
            str= sc.nextLine();
            int l=str.length();
            for (int k=0;k<l;k++)
            {
                if (k%2==0)
                    s1=s1+str.charAt(k); 
                else if(k%2!=0)
                    s2=s2+str.charAt(k);
            }
            System.out.println(s1+" "+s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indent your code properly for readability. Your IDE can do that for you — and for us. Otherwise it’s a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your solution a bit. It should work.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {    String s1="",s2="";
            String str;
            str= sc.nextLine();
            int l=str.length();
            for (int k=0;k<l;k++)
            {
                if(k%2==0)
                    s1=s1+str.charAt(k);
                else if(k%2!=0)
                    s2=s2+str.charAt(k);
            }
            System.out.println(s1+" "+s2);
        }
        sc.close();
```

Edit:
Also, you were iterating (n+1) times

Comment: thanks but i ant to know what does parse int do to accet integer

Comment: It doesn't accept integer, it converts the string into integer value

Comment: While it works, some explanation how your modifications made it work would be nice. It’s from the explanations that we all learn.

Comment: Agreed, thanks @OleV.V.